# Excel: Vertically delineate and convert to column

Tags: excel, csv, transform

Is it possible at all to take a single column excel file and convert it into rowed sections based on a cell? The main issue is that the sections are not an equal number of rows. For example I'd want to take this:

```
Frank
USA
Example Title
Example Post
Next
Jeff
USA
Example Title
Example Post
Example Tag
Next
```

And turn it into this:

```
Frank | USA | Example Title | Example Post
Jeff | USA | Example Title | Example Post | Example Tag
```

Where | represents a new column. The value "Next" would inform a new row.

Comment: This will take vba, what have you tried?  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.

Comment: No. You have four columns of data in the first row and five in the second. This cannot be done given the information you have provided.

Comment: The macro to  do this shouldn't be too hard to write.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is good to show what you have attempted to do if you want to get help on Stack Overflow.  If you show initiative, people here are more than willing to help when you get stuck.

That being said, as @Scott Craner mentioned in his comment, this will most likely take VBA.  VBA is the coding language used in Excel.  It is simple to learn, and there are many useful web pages to help you with general logic if you get stuck.  Here is an example of what you would aim to accomplish with your Macro (assuming efficiency is not your primary concern):

1. Create temp variables to hold values of cells for the short term.
2. Set up a loop to run through each row in the column you are looking at.  If the value of the cell does not equal `"Next"`, copy the cell's contents and paste the contents in the desired location (`Range`), and increment the *column* of the desired location by 1.  If the cell's contents do say `"Next"`, increment the *row* of the desired location by 1. If the cell's contents contain nothing (`""`), end the loop.
3. Iterate indefinitely while the cell's contents are not equal to `""`